# Prove that the square is not a variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

I am looking for a proof that the standard unit square in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not a variety. To be a variety I only require that it be the solution to a system of polynomial equations.

Comment: Give credit to google. I just typed square is not an algebraic variety into google.

Comment: My guess is you run into problems on the boundary : the edges and vertices.   Like the solution to polynomial equations would be smooth(er). ..